# Backup Restore turns carriage returns to literal strings

Tags: database, backup

I tried backing up and restoring my WP site to a different location. Inside the backup SQL file the posts contain HTML with carriage returns escaped:

```
\\r\\n
```

However after the restore, these now appear inside the posts as literal strings, so the output to the page is now...

> Some text \r\n some more text

Did I chose the wrong restore option or is there a WP setting I missed somewhere? Note. The Db is MariaDb. Everything else seems to have restored perfectly.

Comment: Hi johnny, do you still have access to the original database? Check to see if these strings exist in the original tables too, and try other SQL compatibilies / encodings.

Comment: Just trying the `wp_posts` table I'm trying XML format but every time I import, I get Duplicate Primary key even after dropping the table in the destination Db. Will try the full Db next.

Comment: During the import... SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = `ON`;  PhpMyAdmin is complaining it does not recognise keyword near `ON`. Weird. Import fails.